# Run exe using trigger from Oracle database

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, exe, oracleclient

I am trying to run exe from oracle database.
I want to fire a trigger on insert or updation of a table. Once table is updated i have to run my exe which is in my D drive.

I have tried scheduler but it gives error.
my code is as follows:

```
BEGIN
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_PROGRAM (
program_name            => 'program_name',
program_type            => 'EXECUTABLE',
program_action          => 'D:/myproc.exe',
enabled                 => TRUE,
comments                => 'run exe'
);
END;
/
```

I am getting following error

> ORA-27486: insufficient privileges
>   ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_ISCHED", line 5
>   ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER", line 36
>   ORA-06512: at line 2

I have one more question.

Which is best method to run exe? from database or from code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: So your Oracle server is running Windows and you have copied that executable to the Oracle server's `d:` drive?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes

Comment: "*insufficient privileges*" - either the Oracle process is not allowed access to the executable (by Windows), or the user under which the job runs is not allowed to run external executables.

Comment: if i save exe on server only then it will allow me to run exe?

Comment: Do you have the "create job" (or "create any job") privilege granted directly to your schema (ie. not via a role)?

Answer (score 1):

You could schedule the script using **DBMS_SCHEDULER**.

Depending on your **OS**(below example in Windows) you could something like this:

```
BEGIN  
  dbms_scheduler.create_job('MY_JOB',  
  job_action=>'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CMD.EXE',  
  number_of_arguments=>3,  
  job_type=>'executable',  
  start_date => SYSTIMESTAMP,  
  repeat_interval => 'freq=hourly; byminute=0,30; bysecond=0;',  
  end_date => NULL,  
  enabled=> false);  
  dbms_scheduler.set_job_argument_value('MY_JOB',1,'/q');  
  dbms_scheduler.set_job_argument_value('MY_JOB',2,'/c');  
  dbms_scheduler.set_job_argument_value('MY_JOB',3, 'D:/my_sql.bat.bat');  
  dbms_scheduler.enable('MY_JOB');  
END;  
/
```

Now your my_sql.bat would look like:

```
sqlplus user@sid/password @D:\scripts\script.sql  
exit
```

Comment: i am still getting same error. actually i want to run exe on table insertion or updation. is it possible using schedular?

Comment: This is potentially a bad idea. What is the exe going to do?

Comment: @Boneist I mostly work on *Nix and actually never did practically any sscheduling on Windows based server. I just know it could be done in this way on Windows based server. I usally do not like idea of controlling OS from within the database.

Comment: @LalitKumarB Sorry, my comment was directed to the OP, not you *{:-) I keep forgetting to put the name at the front of my comments, duh!

Comment: @Boneist Ah! lol...I hope OP answers to your question, it would tell us what exactly is his requirement.

Comment: there are some loopholes when I use schedular,and I cant call exe from trigger directly. Is there any other way?